# Feedback of the smart gate drivers

Tags: power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, feedback, gate-driving

I have seen a smart gate driver DRV8353RH being used with a three phase motor. There are also input feedback pins to the gate driver that senses the voltages and this could be used to do speed calculations etc.

The problem is that when there is no power being provided to the gate driver IC or the system is turned off then when the motor is turned, it acts as a generator and it in turns turns on all the system and the other ICs as well due to the feedback. Is my judgement correct that the system turns on due to the feedback.

Is there any sort of connection that also powers the rails of VIN and this in turns powers others ICs also? Also what could be the solution to stop this as fluctuations in the rpm of the motor changes the voltage levels and in turns changes the voltages for the other ICs also if my judgement is correct?

A sample schematic is shown below:

[image]

Comment: _”Is my judgement correct that the system turns on due to the feedback.”_ Is back-feed perhaps the word you are looking for? Feedback is normally a small signal and not something which powers anything.

Comment: `Is my judgement correct that the system turns on due to the feedback.` When the motor is rotated (mechanical drive) while the system is off the generated voltage will be applied to the bus (VDRAIN, as indicated in the datasheet) by full-wave rectification via the body diodes of the driver MOSFETs. The datasheet suggests separate supplies for gate driver, shunt amplifier, etc. So if these voltages are generated from VDRAIN (the voltage that is applied to drain/motor) then yes, rotating the motor will power the system.

Comment: The Vdrain is common and a single supply is used for that. When the main voltage is turned OFF then there is no main voltage. The gate is also inactivated, then how does the power go.